# How to NOT print out the memory location python

Tags: python

I'm creating this program and one of its functions is to output a list that is initialized in the constructor. But, what's happening is that it is outputting the memory location in hexadecimal or something and I don't know why.

I have two classes and a run class:

```py
class Person :
def __init__(self, name, ID, age, location, destination):
    self.name = name
    self.ID = ID
    self.age = age
    self.location = location
    self.destination = destination


def introduce_myself(self):
    print("Hi, my name is " + self.name + " , my ID number is " + str(self.ID) + " I am " + str(self.age) + " years old")

def get_route(self):
    return self.location + self.destination


def add2bus(self, Bus):
    if Person.get_route(self) == Bus.get_route() :
        Bus.get_on(Bus)

    else :
        print("not compatible")

def get_name(self):
   print(self.name)

import People

class Bus :
def __init__(self, name, capacity, location, destination):
    self.bus_name = name
    self.bus_capacity = capacity
    self.bus_location = location
    self.bus_destination = destination
    self.seats = []
    self.people = []


def Bus_properties(self):
    print(self.bus_name + ", " + str(self.bus_capacity) + ", " + self.bus_location + ", " + self.bus_destination)

def print_list(self):
    a = self.people
    print(self.people)

def get_route(self):
    return self.bus_location + self.bus_destination

def get_on(self, Person):
    if len(self.people) < 20: #Loop through all the seats
        self.people.append(Person)
    else:
        print('fulll')

def get_name(self):
    print(self.name)



import People
import Transport

C2C = Transport.Bus("C2C", 30, "Ithaca", "New York")
Fred = People.Person("Fred", 12323, 13, "Ithaca", "New York")
Jennifer = People.Person("Jennifer", 111117, 56, "Ithaca", "New York")

Fred.add2bus(C2C)
Jennifer.add2bus(C2C)
```

I want to create a while loop that takes the length of the peoplelist and with the condition while x < len(C2C.people) then it appends all the names of the people on that bus to a list y

like this...

```
x = 0
y = []

while x < len(C2C.people) :
    y.append((C2C.people[x].get_name()))
    x = x + 1
    print(y)
```

but I'm getting this as a result:
Fred
[None]
Jennifer
[None, None]

Comment: If it says something like `Person object at <MEMORY LOCATION>`, then all you need to do is define a `__str__` method in your `Person` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're sending the bus as the person in the add2bus method.

```
def add2bus(self, Bus):
        if Person.get_route(self) == Bus.get_route() :
            Bus.get_on(Bus)

        else :
            print("not compatible")
```

So this will take C2C as the bus object, and then call C2C.get_on(C2C)

Instead you want to do:

```
Bus.get_on(self)
```

Then to get the name of the person, you can do it like this.

```
C2C.people[0].get_name().
```

Calling this will print the passenger's name, but what you want to do is get the name of the passenger back as a string, which is what return does.
So in the get_name() method of people instead of doing print(self.name), return it. Now the statement above will become the string self.name.

Like this:

```
def get_name(self):
   return self.name
```

When you want to do your loop, it should work as you expect now.

If you want me to go into any more detail, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: i tried that!!!! I get this outpout

  print(C2C.people[0].get_name())
  File "D:\Python\Last Day it 01\LSAT DAY\Transport.py", line 30, in get_name
    print(self.name)
AttributeError: 'Bus' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: did you include the parentheses () ?

Comment: hang on, just read the code again a lot of things don't make any sense.

Comment: There's a guy I see at least once/week on my way to work who's always telling the bus to get on the bus, and demanding that random inanimate objects tell him their names. (Although he usually calls the `whatsyername_punk()` function, not the `get_name()` function.)

Comment: @mbdavis i cant do that because my get on unction takes on two arguements, bus, and person. this is because i need to append Person into the list people

Comment: your get_on function takes on self and person. When you call Bus.get_on(self) from the person class, although confusing to look at, get_on is recieving the Bus as the first parameter (self) and self as the second parameter, which is the current person. I've tested it with your code, and it works for me!

Comment: Nevermind it doesn't work. The reason I'm trying to do this, is becuse im trying to create a while loop that outputs the names of everyone in the list. So this is actually what Im going to run in the main program in the end


x = 0
y = []

while x < len(C2C.people) :
    y.append((C2C.people[x].get_name))
    x = x + 1
    
print(y)

Comment: @Panthy it's printing none, because you're doing print(C2C.people[1].get_name()). you don't need the print now, just simply C2C.people[1].get_name() is going to print the name.

Comment: Oh wow it works, but its not appending it to the list like i want it too. It;s outputting it like this:

Fred (new line)
Jennifer

Comment: @Panthy this answer does what you asked, it prints the name! If you want, edit your original question to include the extra section you're referring to now and I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33311/discussion-between-panthy-and-mbdavis)

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `print()` function (or statement, pre 3.0), python asks the objecs you are printing to convert themselves to strings; via the `__str__` function.  Since `object` defines this method for you, it always works; but the predefined version is not very helpful (in the way you are seeing).

Provide your own.  It takes no arguments and *must* return a string:

```
class Foo: 
    bar = 'baz'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Friendly Foo Description: " + bar
```

Comment: yeah but in this case i have

class Bus:

self.people = []

then i wrote

def __str__(self):
   return self.people

but it doesnt change anything

Comment: `self.people` is clearly not a string.  make sure you write a useful `__str__` method for every class you write.

Answer (score 2):

As @inspectorG4dget said, define a `__str__` method to override what gets printed.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
...
>>> print(A())
<__main__.A object at 0x10ca829d0>
>>>
>>> class B(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "I am a B"
...
>>> print(B())
I am a B
```